# How to remove wishlist

Tags: wishlist

can seems to move wishlist from top.link; i was able to move or remove all the link including compare link after hours of searching online, this code only work for the rigister link and account link is not working for the wishlist, if anyone know how to remove kindly share: below is the code i have tried

```
    <referenceBlock name="my-account-link" remove="true" />         <!--for My Account Link-->
</referenceBlock>
```

Comment: What version of Magento?  Please use a tag to show us the version

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume Magento 1.9.x because it seems to be the most popular of questions right now although 2.x.x is catching up.

If you would like to disable the module you can:

1) Go to your Admin Panel configuration by logging into your admin then going to:   system -> config.

2) From here, choose your website / store view in top left (most of you will use default config I believe).

3) Go down to the "Advanced" area on the left and click "advanced".

4) Click on "Disable Modules Output"

5) Find the "Mage_Wishlist" and select "Disable".

Answer (score 0):

Replace `name="my-account-link"` with `name="wish-list-link"`.

Answer (score 0):

administration screenshots 
**Configurations > Customers > Wish List> General options> Enabled: No**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're developing an Enterprise Edition site, `wish-list-link` is not the droid you're looking for. That block is removed and replaced with `multiple-wish-list-link`, thus needs to be removed as follows, in `app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<Theme>/Magento_MultipleWishlist/layout/default.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="multiple-wish-list-link" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Note this will leave wishlish enabled, so users will still be able to add products to, and view, the wishlist. If you wish to disable the wishlist completely, you should follow the instructions in some of the other answers for disabling the module in the admin panel.